# jQuery-File-Upload send proper response

Tags: java, jquery, google-app-engine

Trying to use the Java App engine example, [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine-Java).  I keep getting an error of empty upload file. My rest/file/{key}/meta looks like this

```
[{"name":"243739_694783416343_2004680911_o.jpg","size":41992,"url":"/rest/file/4UH8_IOX5NcMXFX8Kfy_BQ","delete_url":"/rest/file/4UH8_IOX5NcMXFX8Kfy_BQ","delete_type":"DELETE"}]
```

which seems to be a proper response.

I have realized that the images are being stored to the blobstore.  I just need to let the client know the file was successfully uploaded.

Also, I can't get multiple uploads working.  It seems the upload session expires after the first upload is started.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Been working hard to get this set up.  Spent all day yesterday properly setting up jersey to get the json outputting properly.

Comment: Please post your full code so that I can help you with HTML Upload Form as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json needs to be in the format

```
{"files":[{"name":"243739_694783416343_2004680911_o.jpg","size":41992,"url":"/rest/file/4UH8_IOX5NcMXFX8Kfy_BQ","delete_url":"/rest/file/4UH8_IOX5NcMXFX8Kfy_BQ","delete_type":"DELETE"}]}
```